# JSON nested Parsing Help using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is sample JSON response. I need to parse this in a generic way instead of using transactionList.transaction[0].

```
"rateType": interestonly,
"relationshipId": consumer,
"sourceCode": null,
"subType": null,
"transactionList": {
    "transaction": [
      {
        "amount": {
          "currencyCode": "USD",
          "value": 1968.99
        },
        "customData": {
          "valuePair": [
            {
              "name": "valuePair",
              "value": "001"
            }
          ]
        },
        "dateTimePosted": null,
        "description": "xyz",
        "id": "01",
        "interestAmount": {
          "currencyCode": "USD",
          "value": 1250
        },
        "merchantCategoryCode": 987654321,
        "principalAmount": {
          "currencyCode": "USD",
          "value": 1823.8
        },
        "source": "Mobile Deposit",
        "status": "Posted",
        "type": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I am using the following code to parse json

```
$.each(jsonDataArr, recursive);

function recursive(key, val) {
    if (val instanceof Object) {
        list += "<tr><td colspan='2'>";
        list += key + "</td></tr>";
        $.each(val, recursive);
    } else {
        if(val != null) {
            if(!val.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + val + "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this outputs as **transactionList**
**transaction**
**0** and then the other keys & values. I was hoping to get transactionList and all the keys and values instead of getting the transaction and the array element. So I guess my parsing logic is not correct. Can anyone help me address this so I can just have the transactionList displayed? Thanks for your help inadvance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to display a table with all your data. I added border=1 to the tables to visualize the boxes. See an example in http://output.jsbin.com/wuwoga/7/embed?js,output

```
function display(data) {
  var html = "<table border='1'>";
  var lists = recursive(data);
  html += lists + "</table>";
  return html;
}

function recursive(json) {
  var list = "";
  var instanceObj = false;

  $.each(json, function(key, val){
    instanceObj = (val instanceof Object);

    list += [
      "<tr>",
      "<td>" + key + "</td>",
      (instanceObj) ? 
         "<td><table border='1'>" + recursive(val) + "</table></td>" :
             "<td>" + val + "</td>",
      "</tr>"
    ].join("");
  });

  return list;
}
```

If you call `display(json)` with the json below, you'd get a display of all your data. If you add more data in the transaction array, it will display that too

```
var json = {
  "rateType": "interestonly",
  "relationshipId": "consumer",
  "sourceCode": null,
  "subType": null,
  "transactionList": {
    "transaction": [
      {
    "amount": {
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "value": 1968.99
    },
    "customData": {
      "valuePair": [
        {
          "name": "valuePair",
          "value": "001"
        }
      ]
    },
    "dateTimePosted": null,
    "description": "xyz",
    "id": "01",
    "interestAmount": {
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "value": 1250
    },
    "merchantCategoryCode": 987654321,
    "principalAmount": {
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "value": 1823.8
    },
    "source": "Mobile Deposit",
    "status": "Posted",
    "type": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It would help if we had an example of your desired results.
What if there are multiple transactions in the transactionList, how would it be displayed?

Essentially your issue is that Arrays are Objects as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/v0gcroou/

```
if (transactionList.transaction instanceof Object) == true
Key of transactionList.transaction is 0
```

Instead you need to also test if the object is an array, and do something else based on the fact you're now parsing an array instead of a string or JSON object

```
(Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Array]')
```

Another easy way would be to check the `'number' === typeof key` since your JSON object does not contain numeric keys, but array objects inherently do.

http://jsfiddle.net/h66tsm9u/